# Trouble with rewriting formulas in different forms

Tags: algebra-precalculus

We have the following formulas:

$$ a = \dfrac{\displaystyle\sum (x-\bar{x})(y-\bar{y})}{\displaystyle\sum(x-\bar{x})^2}$$

$$ r = \dfrac{ \displaystyle \sum (x-\bar{x})(y-\bar{y})}{\sqrt{\displaystyle\sum(x-\bar{x})^2 \cdot \displaystyle\sum(y-\bar{y})^2}}$$

Using the above formula, rewrite them into these:

$$ a = \dfrac {n \displaystyle \sum xy - \displaystyle \sum x \displaystyle \sum y}{n \displaystyle \sum x^2 - (\displaystyle \sum x)^2}$$

$$ a = r \cdot \dfrac{\sigma_y}{\sigma_x}$$

Can anyone help me, I don't know how to do this. $a$ is the slope and $r$ is the correlation coefficient. Also:

$$\sigma_y = \dfrac{\sqrt{\displaystyle\sum(y-\bar{y})^2}}{n}$$

$$\sigma_x = \dfrac{\sqrt{\displaystyle\sum(x-\bar{x})^2}}{n}$$

Comment: Are you comfortable with $\Sigma$-notation for sums?

Comment: For example, $\Sigma x = \Sigma_{i=1}^n x_i = x_1 + \cdots + x_n$.

Comment: @SammyBlack Yes I am, why?

Comment: Well, I wanted to get a feel for what level of response I ought to give, but it seems that Ross Millikan beat me to it.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the numerator of $a$, note that $\bar x= \frac 1n \sum x$.  We have $$\\ \sum (x-\bar{x})(y-\bar{y})=\sum (xy-x \bar y - \bar xy+\bar x \bar y)\\=\sum xy-\bar y\sum x -\bar x \sum y +n\bar x \bar y\\=\sum xy-\frac 2n\left(\sum x\right)\left(\sum y\right)+\frac 1n\left(\sum x\right)\left(\sum y\right)\\=\frac 1n\left(n\sum xy -\left(\sum x\right)\left(\sum y\right) \right)$$

The others are similar.  The denominator will have a factor $\frac 1n$ as well to cancel the one we got here.